# Getting CS:GO Market Price history

Tags: json, ajax, steam

I'm trying to get a data from steam market from this plot:

[image: steam plot here]

I'm trying to get this data using this url

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Frontside%20Misty%20%28Field-Tested%29
```

According to economy.js file from steam market page

```
new Ajax.Request( 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/', {
        method: 'get',
        parameters: {
            appid: this.m_item.appid,
            market_hash_name: GetMarketHashName( this.m_item )
        },
        onSuccess: function( transport ) { SellItemDialog.OnPriceHistorySuccess( transport ); },
        onFailure: function( transport ) { SellItemDialog.OnPriceHistoryFailure( transport ); }
} );
```

But when try to open `http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Frontside%20Misty%20%28Field-Tested%29` in my browser i always get empty [] result.

On the other hand, when I'm logged in my account in browser, the result is not empty and everything is fine.
But this plot is always available at the http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Frontside%20Misty%20%28Field-Tested%29 page for me and it does not matter i'm in my account or not.

How to get this data properly and without auth?

Comment: [You won't be able to do this without logging in](https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamBot/comments/3ai3mv/400_bad_request_when_downloading_price_history/).

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on an API that gives you as much data as possible from the CSGO market sales. I'm tracking **6,269** items with **~1,028,619,499** successful sales worth **~$1,155,921,513**.

One endpoint that could be used for those graph values is `http://csgolyzer.com/api/history/{market_hash_name}?key={your_api_key}`

This returns this response:

```
[
    {
        median_price: "0.34",
        sold_at: "2015-12-20 01:00:00"
    },
    {
        median_price: "0.32",
        sold_at: "2015-12-21 01:00:00"
    },
    ...
]
```

---

The API docs are available here: http://csgolyzer.com/docs

There are also other endpoints for more data about Market Sales and the API rates are better than querying Steam yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just scrape the history from the market listing page.